# Broadcast your internet ip

Tags: networking

i want to do something like broadcasting my application over internet using my ip.

I have a static IP say `a.b.c.d` and want to deploy some application say a war file in tomcat on port 8080 so that some remote friend of mine who is not on network can access it over internet using `http://a.b.c.d:8080` in browser. i have windows vista/XP installed on my system.

thanks, hope i made the question clear i am still confused with it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly have a static IP, and your computer is not behind a NAT box or firewall, then if a.b.c.d is that static address, what you've described will simply work. If you *do* have a firewall, you have to add an exception to allow requests in. If you've got a NAT box, which you would use to share that static IP among computers, then you need to set the NAT box up to forward requests on that one port to your computer. FInally, if you want a.b.c.d to be a name, rather than numbers, then you need to register a domain name with a registrar like GoDaddy.com  and pay some money.

Comment: wont i need to open a port from my modem??? so that it handles any incoming and outgoing calls from outer world?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by "set the NAT box up to forward requests on that one port." Different words, same idea.

Comment: @Ernest- i am using windows OS do i need to do something in C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts so that its accessible from outside world?

Comment: No, the hosts file helps *your* computer look up other computers. If you want other people to look up *yours*, then *they* could put something in their hosts file -- or, as is more traditional, you could pay a registrar to keep the same information in the DNS system.

Comment: @Ernest - i am not getting what settings to be done on NAT. i have DNA-A212 ADSL2+Wireless Modem whats to be done on this any idea??? it has 2-3 options for NAT port fwding

Comment: Whatever port you want outside users to get to, you need to forward that to the LAN address of your computer. In your example above, you want to forward TCP port 8080 to whatever IP your Windows networking control panel thinks your computer is using -- 192.168.1.something, probably.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dyndns and set up a domain for your friend to access. www.dyndns.com

> Dynamic DNS service allows you to point a hostname to a dynamic or static IP address or URL.

Comment: If the IP address is static anyway DynDNS would be merely cosmetic. Nicer, but cosmetic.

Comment: That's true. My apologies. 
It would be easier for the friend to access though, rather than having to remember the http://a.b.c.d:8080.

Comment: i have prior knowledge on using dyndns thats best  suited for dynamic ips.